# How to Copy Files Fast

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

What is the fastest way to copy files in a python program?

It takes at least 3 times longer to copy files with `shutil.copyfile()` versus to a regular right-click-copy > right-click-paste using Windows File Explorer or Mac's Finder.
Is there any faster alternative to `shutil.copyfile()` in Python? What could be done to speed up a file copying process? (The files destination is on the network drive... if it makes any difference...).

#### EDITED LATER:

Here is what I have ended up with:

```
def copyWithSubprocess(cmd):        
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

win=mac=False
if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):mac=True
elif sys.platform.startswith("win"):win=True

cmd=None
if mac: cmd=['cp', source, dest]
elif win: cmd=['xcopy', source, dest, '/K/O/X']

if cmd: copyWithSubprocess(cmd)
```

Comment: You can use the native command line options like `cp` for Linux & Mac and `COPY` for Windows. They should be as fast as when you use the GUI.

Comment: On Windows SHFileOperation gives you the native shell file copy

Comment: Depending on some factors not stated in the question it could be beneficial to pack the files into a compressed archive before transmission... Have you considered using something like rsync?

Comment: If you are concerned with ownership and ACL don't use shutil for that reason alone:  ['On Windows, file owners, ACLs and alternate data streams are not copied.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#shutil) '

Comment: If I use the native operation system's commands (such as OSX cp) should I be then using subprocess? Is there any Python module to call cp directly without a need for a subprocess on Mac?

Comment: It's worth noting that in Python 3.8 functions that copy files and directories [have been optimized](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil-platform-dependent-efficient-copy-operations) to work faster on several major OS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fastest version w/o overoptimizing the code I've got with the following code:

```
class CTError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, errors):
        self.errors = errors

try:
    O_BINARY = os.O_BINARY
except:
    O_BINARY = 0
READ_FLAGS = os.O_RDONLY | O_BINARY
WRITE_FLAGS = os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC | O_BINARY
BUFFER_SIZE = 128*1024

def copyfile(src, dst):
    try:
        fin = os.open(src, READ_FLAGS)
        stat = os.fstat(fin)
        fout = os.open(dst, WRITE_FLAGS, stat.st_mode)
        for x in iter(lambda: os.read(fin, BUFFER_SIZE), ""):
            os.write(fout, x)
    finally:
        try: os.close(fin)
        except: pass
        try: os.close(fout)
        except: pass

def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=[]):
    names = os.listdir(src)

    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignore:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                copyfile(srcname, dstname)
            # XXX What about devices, sockets etc.?
        except (IOError, os.error), why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        except CTError, err:
            errors.extend(err.errors)
    if errors:
        raise CTError(errors)
```

This code runs a little bit slower than native linux "cp -rf".

Comparing to shutil the gain for the local storage to tmfps is around 2x-3x and around than 6x for NFS to local storage.

After profiling I've noticed that shutil.copy does lots of fstat syscals which are pretty heavyweight.
If one want to optimize further I would suggest to do a single fstat for src and reuse the values. Honestly I didn't go further as I got almost the same figures as native linux copy tool and optimizing for several hundrends of milliseconds wasn't my goal.

Comment: Not sure if this is specific to later versions of python (3.5+), but the sentinel in `iter` needs to be `b''` in order to stop. (At least on OSX)

Comment: doesn't work with python 3.6 even after fixing 'except' syntax

Comment: This is a python2 version. I haven't tested this with python3. Probably python3 native filetree copy is fast enough, one shall do a benchmark.

Comment: This is way faster than anything else I tried.

Comment: FYI I would suggest adding `shutil.copystat(src, dst)` after the file is written out to bring over metadata.

Comment: @Dmytro Just tested in py3.6, still 3x faster than shutil.copy2()!

Comment: @Spencer What did you changed in the code to make it work with python 3.5+ ?, Best regards!

Comment: @Varlor From what I remember I just changed this one line to the following: `for x in iter(lambda: os.read(fin, BUFFER_SIZE), b""):` (made the string into bytes by adding 'b')

Comment: ah, because I get also a syntax error with the 'why' in the except line 'except (IOError, os.error), why:'

Comment: To boost performance also see the [pyfastcopy](https://pypi.org/project/pyfastcopy/) module which uses the system call sendfile(). This module works for Python 2 and 3. All you have to do is literally "import pyfastcopy" and shutils will automatically perform better. Like @Morwenn mentioned above, Python 3.8 will have sendfile() built into its impl.

Comment: I've tried to replace `shutil.copyfile` by the `copyfile` from the example under python `3.8.0`, but it seems hanged in the `for x in iter` loop.

Comment: @VahidPazirandeh `pyfastcopy` does not work on Windows: *The ``sendfile`` system call does not exist on Windows, so importing this module will have no effect.*

Comment: For those trying to get the best performance, buffer size is VERY important https://www.zabkat.com/blog/buffered-disk-access.htm

Answer (score 6):

You could simply just use the OS you are doing the copy on, for Windows:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["xcopy", "c:\\file.txt", "n:\\folder\\", "/K/O/X"])
```

/K - Copies attributes. Typically, Xcopy resets read-only attributes

/O - Copies file ownership and ACL information.

/X - Copies file audit settings (implies /O).

Comment: Would "xcopy" on Windows work with a "regular" subprocess, such as:                                                                                    cmd = ['xcopy', source, dest, "/K/O/X"]       subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: That will work as well.

Comment: Invalid number of parameters error

Comment: Note that the /O and /X flags require an elevated subprocess, else you will result in "Access denied"

Comment: This is a very fast option for single-file copies, but for anyone out there trying to thread large numbers of files it can run far slower (9x in a recent test of 4000 files). I was able to get better results modifying copy2 buffer size as in other answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import subprocess

def copyWithSubprocess(cmd):        
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

cmd=None
if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"): cmd=['cp', source, dest]
elif sys.platform.startswith("win"): cmd=['xcopy', source, dest, '/K/O/X']

if cmd: copyWithSubprocess(cmd)
```

Comment: Economic on explanations, but this is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a guess but ... **your timing it wrong** ... that is when you copy the file it opens the file and reads it all into memory so that when you paste you only create a file and dump your memory contents

in python

```
copied_file = open("some_file").read()
```

is the equivelent of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> copy

then

```
with open("new_file","wb") as f:
     f.write(copied_file)
```

is the equivelent of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> paste (so time that for equivelency ....)

if you want it to be more scalable to larger data (but its not going to be as fast as ctrl+v /ctrl+c

```
with open(infile,"rb") as fin,open(outfile,"wb") as fout:
     fout.writelines(iter(fin.readline,''))
```

Comment: I believe you would be a good instructor, nice!

Comment: Good point. I should be more specific. Instead of right-click-copy and then paste: This schema: 1. Select files; 2. Drag files. 3 Drop files onto a destination folder.

Comment: thats a move then ... which is much different ... try `shutil.move` instead

Comment: In win it could be a move. In osx it could be a copy.

Comment: This solution does not scale. As the files get large this becomes a less usable solution. You would need to make multiple system calls to the OS to still read portions of the file into memory as files get large.

Comment: this was a question about timings ... and it was basically pointing out his operations were not equivelent

Comment: I find it hard to believe that if you CTRL + C a 100 gigabyte file in Windows it attempts to load that in memory right then and there...

Comment: theres more than a grain of truth to that im sure ... perhaps i oversimplified it