# How can I copy large files from one directory to other directory with less time in Data Lake through Databricks?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-lake, databricks

I'm trying to copy **20GB** files from one folder to another folder in **Azure Data Lake** and want to achieve it through Data Bricks.
I have tried the below code but it is taking more then an hour.
Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this with less then **20 minutes**?

```
import shutil, os
shutil.copytree("/dbfs/mnt/storage1/ABC/", "/dbfs/mnt/storage1/copied/")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to Copy Files Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078621/python-how-to-copy-files-fast)

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be using dbutils.fs.

This would do it for you:

```
 dbutils.fs.cp ("/mnt/storage1/ABC/", "/mnt/storage1/copied/", recurse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the azure.datalake.store library, more details here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python

That should prevent databricks download and re-uploading the file.